# Unable To Create Temp File by OpenCpu On Linux Server

Tags: r, api, putty, opencpu

Today we installed opencpu on Linux server. After that all packages are properly loaded but temporary file is not getting created. If  we pass value and converted into json  like

-d ‘x=10'

It is giving only encrypted URL  like : -

```
http:&#x2F;&#x2F;hostname.server.com:8080&#x2F;auth-sign-in?appUri=%2Fp%2F5656%2Focpu%2Flibrary%2Fmypack12%2FR%2Fhostname@example.com8080:~$
```

We refer below URL but gives same output as above

If we work on local machine on windows, it is properly working. It would really help if someone can look into the above issue and suggest resolution or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be accessing the OpenCPU server via `Hostname/p/5656/ocpu` (which looks like the rstudio ide built-in proxy) but directly via `http://Hostname/ocpu`.

It looks like your rstudio proxy server intercepts the api request to redirect to a authentication page.

The OpenCPU server builds on Apache2, you don't need RStudio at all. You can use RStudio to write R code if you like, but the two are completely unrelated.

Comment: I installed opencpu on server and also uploaded the simple program for opencpu on mypack12 package. the package is successfully loaded on browser, however the temp file is not created.
Input command on Putty:
hostname:~$ curl servername@example.com:8787/p/5656/ocpu/library/mypack12/R/sqrt12 -d 'b=10'

Expected output on Terminal : something like this
 /ocpu/tmp/x032a8fee/R/.val



Actual output on Putty: http:&#x2F;&#x2F;servername@example.com:8787&#x2F;auth-sign-in?appUri=%2Fp%2F5656%2Focpu%2Flibrary%2Fmypack12%2FR%2Fsqrt12phostname:~$ hostname